# Array Values Refer To Variables

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to write a script in bash that "builds" an array from seven variables. For example:

```
a=7
b=3
c=5
....
declare -a elem_arr=( "$a" "$b" "$c"..."$g" )
echo "$elem_arr[1]" # this doesn't echo anything.
if [ "$elem_arr[1]" -ne "$elem_arr[2] ]; then
   echo "$elem_arr[1] is not equal to $elem_arr[2]"
fi
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to construct an array in such manner?

Comment: what happens if you assign like `...elem_arr=($a $b $c ...$g)`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it doesn't work. It echos an empty line

Comment: what do you get if you type `echo $SHELL; bash --version` ? And you need to use the extra curly braces around var name as @nosid has indicated. Good luck.

Comment: Without curly braces it should print the value of elem_array[0] followed by "[1]"; if it's not even printing the "[1]", there's something wrong with the `echo` that you'll have to fix before you can even tell if the array part is working.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```
    #! /bin/bash

    a="This"
    b="script"
    c="works!"

    count=1
    for i in $( echo $a $b $c )
    do
         array[$count]=$i
         count=$[ $count+1 ]
    done

    echo "${array[1]} ${array[2]} ${array[3]}"
```

This script works by using a for loop to define each element in the array individually. You can then easily call any element using the default syntax `${array[index]}`

Comment: I don't get why this was down voted, it does exactly what you ask for and works successfully.